# Polymorphic Subclass Object method in Array not working

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, foreach, polymorphism

first off I tried researching my problem but I have no idea how to word my question ... so I am not sure if there is a question out there that solves my problem and also not sure if this is the best wording for my question either.

So, I have a Superclass Shape

```
public abstract class Shape {
protected String name;
protected String type;
public Shape(){
    name = "";
    type = "";
}
public void print (){
    System.out.printf("Name = %s, Type = %s", name, type);
}

}
```

and a Subclass 2D

```
public abstract class TwoDimensionalShape extends Shape{
protected double length;
protected double area;
public TwoDimensionalShape(double length){
    if (length<0.0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR: POSITIVE NUMBER REQUIRED");
    this.length = length;
    type = "Two Dimensional Shape";
}
public abstract void getArea();
@Override
public void print(){
System.out.printf("Name = %s, Type = %s, Length of side = %d, Area = %d",
name, type, length, area);
}
}
```

along with several smaller subclasses that extend off 2D (and another almost identical class 3D). My problem is with the test code, it doesn't calculate area. Class Test code

```
Circle S1 = new Circle(2.5);
etc.
shapesArray[0] = S1;
etc.
for(Shape CS : shapesArray){
CS.getArea();
if(CS.Type == "Three Dimensional Shape"){
CS.getVolume();
}
CS.print();
System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

I removed the getArea and getVolume methods and the print statement worked fine. Which lead me to think there is a problem with the way each subclass interacts with the superclass, however, the subclass print methods override and return the correct values (except for area :(   )

With the area and volume commands, the code doesn't compile and I get this error

ShapeTest.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                CS.getArea();

three times.

Here is one of the subclasses, in case it holds important info needed for a solution.

```
public class Circle extends TwoDimensionalShape {
public Circle(double length){
    super(length);
    name = "Circle";
}
@Override
public void getArea(){
    area = Math.PI * length * length;
}
@Override
public void print(){
System.out.printf("Name = %s, Type = %s, Radius = %f, Area = %f",
name, type, length, area);
}
}
```

I am not experienced enough to understand the problem entirely and I have been changing loops, location of variables and methods in the classes but I have not made progress. I thank you for reading this long question and id appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: And hint: you have a bug in there ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java ... do nut use == ... it simply looks like you are overburdening yourself right now. You should probably step back and focus more on the real basics at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type Shape doesn't declare that method.

The compiler doesn't know that you intend to put TwoDimensionalShape  objects into that array. It only see that you said: this array contains Shapes; and shapes do no have those other two methods!

So you could do:

- declare that array to contain only TwoDimensionalShape objects. Of course, then you can't add 3D
- use `if (thing is instanceof TwoDimensionalShape) {` and then cast to that type
- And then: you dont need a **string** type. All objects have a **class**; and that **class** already defines its exact type. That is why you use `instanceof` to determine types; not by adding a string field and comparing that string (the wrong way with ==)  to other strings!

Comment: Your explanation has helped me understand the fault, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your super most class Shape should have all the methods you want to access through polymorphic feature of java. 
One would assign a sub-type instance of to a supertype variable to handle all possible subtype classes in a uniform fashion, e.g. using methods declared (but possibly overriden) by the supertype class.

I have made minor changes to your classes.

```
abstract class Shape {
    protected String name;
    protected String type;

    public Shape() {
        name = "";
        type = "";
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("Name = %s, Type = %s", name, type);
    }

    public abstract void getArea();

    public abstract void getVolume();

}
// ----------------
abstract class TwoDimensionalShape extends Shape {
    protected double length;
    protected double area;

    public TwoDimensionalShape(double length) {
        if (length < 0.0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "ERROR: POSITIVE NUMBER REQUIRED");
        this.length = length;
        type = "Two Dimensional Shape";
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.printf(
                "Name = %s, Type = %s, Length of side = %d, Area = %d", name,
                type, length, area);
    }
}
//------------------
class Circle extends TwoDimensionalShape {
    public Circle(double length) {
        super(length);
        name = "Circle";
    }

    @Override
    public void getArea() {
        area = Math.PI * length * length;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("Name = %s, Type = %s, Radius = %f, Area = %f", name,
                type, length, area);
    }

    @Override
    public void getVolume() {
        System.out.println("Vaolume method invoked");
    }
}
//------------------
public class Dim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape[] shapesArray = new Shape[10];
        Circle S1 = new Circle(2.5);
        shapesArray[0] = S1;
        for (Shape CS : shapesArray) {
            if (CS != null) {
                CS.getArea();
                if (CS.type.equals("Three Dimensional Shape")) {
                    CS.getVolume();
                }
                CS.print();
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Narayana, thank you for posting this answer, I was unsure from the previous comment how to word this    if (CS.type.equals("Three Dimensional Shape")) {
                    CS.getVolume();
                }
thanks for helping